# Is Interface API always constant?

Tags: java, interface

Such as `java.util.Set<E>`, is it guaranteed to be consistent? "Consistent" means that the author will never add or delete or modify the current interface methods. So that my classes implemented it can always work.

In fact, I am thinking about the risks when I use "Composition" instead of "Inheritance". (*Effective Java* Item 16) Once `Set` API changes, the code will broken.

Comment: What do you mean by 'constant'?

Comment: And what do you mean by 'always' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is Interface API always constant?

I assume that you are asking if the `Set` API can ever be changed in an incompatible way.

The only people who can actually guarantee that are Oracle.

I have not seen any guarantees (in writing) from Oracle, but based on past history, there is ZERO chance that they would alter the `Set` API in a way that would impact binary compatibility for user code.

In short: don't worry about it.  Certainly for any of the standard interfaces<sup>1</sup> in Java SE.

---

<sup>1 - The internal interfaces are a different matter; e.g. any APIs in the 
`sun.*` package tree.  However, if you use *them* that's one of the [risks](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html) that you are taking.  Beware!</sup>

Comment: Thanks. In fact, I am thinking about the risks when I use "Composition" instead of "Inheritance". (Effective Java Item 16) Once Set API changes, the code will broken.

Comment: @jinge - well yea.  And once pigs can fly, we should all carry umbrellas!

Comment: The various java specs are the written guarantees, along with the various lengthy processes for modifying these specs. Binary compatibility does break, source compatibility almost never does, behavioural changes also happen occasionally. Oracle publishes extensive documentation about such changes like here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html So this is not really just  'based on past history', there are processes in place to manage it.

Comment: Yes. There are processes, but there is nothing to guarantee Oracle won't ignore the processes if it suits them.  (They are not legally obliged to follow them.)  Really, it is history (and common sense) tells us that they *wouldn't* deliberately break compatibility.  But that's not a guarantee.

Comment: Also, adding or removing methods in an interface could break both source and binary compatibility for classes that implement the interface.  But just breaking binary compatibility would be a major PR disaster.

Comment: I think that's actually demonstrably inaccurate and Oracle does not uniquely control the process but it's a somewhat pointless argument.

Comment: Please show me where Oracle is legally obliged to follow the process.  Show me the "demonstration" of "demonstrably inaccurate".

Comment: Oracle is not some unilateral absolute arbiter of the spec or even the implementation. For one thing, they have many licensees. You're making it sound like the spec can change randomly on Oracle's say so and the only reason we believe it won't is 'history'. This just isn't the case.

Comment: I'm sorry, but given the lawsuit they engaged in with Google, I would not rule out the possibility of unilateral changes ... ignoring process, and the wishes of licensees ... if Oracle management **thought** it was in their interest.  But they would have to be nuts to think that ... and they are NOT nuts.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't worry about it.  Oracle is a business.  If they made a change to one of their common APIs that caused tons of programs to stop working, it would be a big black eye for them and damage their brand.  They're not going to do that.

If they do plan to make an incompatible change, I believe they would start by marking as "deprecated" any method that they're planning to remove in a future release.  There's also a `@Deprecated` annotation, which will cause compilers and IDEs to generate warnings.  This should give users of the feature fair warning that they will need to make changes eventually.  I don't know how long users typically have before they *must* make a change, but it seems to me that some Java features have been marked as deprecated for several releases.  (Exception: *raw* generic types are documented as something that could disappear.  So if you declare an object to be a `Set`, as opposed to a `Set<SomeType>` or `Set<?>`, that *could* break in a future version of Java.)

A caveat: this applies only to properties that are documented in the API.  In the case of `Set`, in particular, the documentation says that if you iterate through a set (e.g. `for (element : mySet)`), the order is undefined unless the actual set is an implementation that says the order is defined.  In particular, it will be undefined for a `HashSet`.  That means that if you write code, intentionally or inadvertently, that only works if the results come out in a certain order, your code could break in the next release.

**EDIT:** As to whether methods could be *added* to an interface: Note that adding methods doesn't break normal code that uses already-provided objects that are instances of the interface, but it could break code that implements the interface.  For interfaces that are provided mainly so that users' code can implement it (e.g. `Runnable`, functional interfaces), adding methods (other than `default` methods) could break a lot of code, so I'd assume they would avoid adding methods for the same reason.  (If they wanted to add a method, they could define a new subinterface.)  For the collection classes like `Set`, it's a bit less clear, since it's more normal for code to use one of the implementations Java already provides; developing one's own implementation seems fairly uncommon.  Still, contrary to my first version of this answer, I wasn't able to find any cases where a non-default method has been added to one of those interfaces.

Comment: If my program has a class MySet<E> implements Set<E>. Then in the next edition Set<E> add a method called `newMethod`, while Myset doesn't override it. It will not break my code?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that you were talking about writing your own class that implements `Set`.  (I reread your question, and think I see where you were asking it, but the grammar problems made it difficult to understand.)  I'll add more information.